# How to read google Filestream content_cache folder?

Tags: sqlite, google-drive-file-stream

I have problem with Google Filestream.

User data was not synchronized to cloud for months. After uninstalling and reinstalling the FS client sync is now working fine...but all locally saved files are lost. We have old content_cache folder with more than 40 Gb data.

There are no id's marked with "local-[number]" in metadata_sqlite_db. Perhaps we do not have latest version of database or client has not been working as planned.

Is there a way to rebuild, parse or read content_cache folder?

There is great discussion about the fs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439810/get-google-drive-files-links-using-drive-file-stream/52107704

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the older version of Google Drive (aka Google Drive File Stream at the time) but i am able to use 7-zip. Just navigate down the folder contents. I.e ...\content_cache\d7\d4\and in there is a file with a random number, say 56783. Open the file in 7-zip file manager. If it has file contents and isn't just a cached file google drive needs for operation, you will open it successfully. You will find the best luck with the larger file sized random numberd files. Some will be kb, some Mb or more.

Good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).